# URL Link gives pop-up of photo with NO URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, xhtml

On this site when you click on an item, an image pops-up with the nutritional data. 
Here is the url: http://www.uniondining.com/WeeklyMenu_182.htm

But i can't seem to find the url of that link, I have looked at the source code, and still can't see it. Under the tag for each item there is an "onclick" attribute, but I can't see what it links to.

For example on Aztec corn here is some of the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" hidefocus="true" id="S1L0000040000044771_06348" onmouseover="wschk(1);" onmouseout="wschk(0);" onclick="rptlist(this);">
<span class="ul" onmouseover="ws(this);" onclick="nf('0000044771_06348');" onmouseout="pcls(this);">Aztec Corn</span>
```

this html is in the table, but the onclick doesn't appear to go anywhere in the html.

I am looking for the url of the pop up with the nutritional info

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" hidefocus="true" id="S1L0000040000044771_06348" onmouseover="wschk(1);" onmouseout="wschk(0);" onclick="rptlist(this);">
<span class="ul" onmouseover="ws(this);" onclick="nf('0000044771_06348');" onmouseout="pcls(this);">Aztec Corn</span>
```

When you click on that link you trigger that nf(x) javascript function, which if you inspect the code you find inside the  tag. That function gets the data accessing the right array with the idx parameter that the function takes in input.

The nf(idx) function just gets the data, calculates all values and then creates the popup on the fly.

```
function nf(idx) {
   if(!ie && !ff && !sa && !ch){alert('Your browser cannot display the Nutrition Facts window.   '); return false;}
   var nvar;
   var cstr = new String(nftext);
   var obj=new Object(aData[idx]);
   // Modify values for FDA here
   var c00=obj[00]; 
   nvar=parseInt(obj[01]);                // calories 
   var c01=((nvar<5) ? 0 : ((nvar>=5 && nvar<=50) ? round(nvar/5,0)*5 : round(nvar/10,0)*10))+'';
   nvar=parseInt(obj[02]);                // fat calories
   var c02=((nvar<5) ? 0 : ((nvar>=5 && nvar<=50) ? round(nvar/5,0)*5 : round(nvar/10,0)*10))+'';
   nvar=round(parseFloat(obj[03]),2);     // fat
   var c03=((nvar<.50) ? 0 : ((nvar>=.50 && nvar<5.00) ? round(round(nvar/.5,0)*.5,1) : round(nvar,0)))+'';

 ETC.

}
   return true;
}
```

and if you notice at the bottom before the closing `</body>` tag, there is all data which populates the popup.

```
aData=new Object();
aData['0000069741_30643']=new Array('6 oz (170g)','170','64','7.10','11','1.10','6','0.00','0','0','546','23','24.60','8','3.20','13','2.50','4.10','22.9','151.2','8.3','10.0','Asian Noodle Stir Fry','Rice Noodles Tossed with Stir Fried Broccoli, Bell Pepper Slivers, Fresh Ginger, & Scallions in a Spicy Tahini Lime Sauc','Contains wheat, peanuts, soy beans, gluten','1146.0','90.7','83.0','1.8','g m ');
aData['0000047339_04062']=new Array('3 oz (85g)','52','28','3.10','5','0.70','4','0.00','7','2','158','7','3.30','1','0.00','0','1.60','2.80','1.2','13.8','0.6','1.7','Asian Pepper Steak','Teriyaki Beef Stir Fried with Yellow Onion and Green Peppers','Contains fish, shellfish, wheat, soy beans, gluten','60.0','8.3','6.0','0.3','');
 ETC...
```

Comment: right I see that data that populates it. So there is no image that is saved some where? When you click it calls that function which finds that data and then puts it in a blank nutritional facts image

Comment: There's no image. It's just html.

Comment: No, the nf(idx) function just gets the data, calculates values and then creates the popup on the fly. No file is saved anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like nf() does not open up a page that is stored on the server. nf() opens up a new window and uses document.write to give the nutritional information to the window.

Answer (score 0):

the data is all inline. view the source code and check right after comment:

"JAVASCRIPT DATA"

Comment: what do u mean? I don't see a url for the pop up